# draft-js-export-html not includes video when export

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

Currently, I'm using draft js editor, add plugin [draft-js-video-plugin](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/tree/master/draft-js-video-plugin) to insert video into editor and use [draft-js-export-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draft-js-export-html) to export html but the htmk result not includes video tag or anythings else.

Console log `stateToHTML(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent())`

```
<p><br></p>
<figure>&nbsp;</figure>
<p><br></p>
```

I found same issue with export image [here](https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-utils/issues/59) and they've resolved but not for video.
I've read [their source code](https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-utils/blob/master/packages/draft-js-export-html/src/stateToHTML.js) on github and seem now they only support text, link and image.

[image]

So how can I get result HTML includes video from draft js? Please help me, thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit to **rafaelespinoza** https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-utils/issues/59#issuecomment-314527096

I'm able to fix it using `entityStyleFn like below:

```
entityStyleFn: (entity) => {
    const entityType = entity.get('type').toLowerCase();
    if (entityType === 'draft-js-video-plugin-video') {
      const data = entity.getData();
      return {
        element: 'video',
        attributes: {
          src: data.src,
        },
      };
    }
    return null;
  },
```

Comment: youtube video can not show on video element